# Changing the type of list items using a CustomModelBinder

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a requirement to bind an entity of type 'Field' which has a List as a property. The list will have mixed types of behaviour, but all inherit from Behaviour. I need the list to bind with the correct derived types so they can be persisted correctly.

I am using a technique used in the DerivedTypesModelBinder in the MvcContrib library, whereby I have a property on each of my entities which holds the type that needs to be created. The field is called 'XxModelTypexX'.

My problem is, I am not sure how to change the type of a property in a custom model binder. Every time I try it simply binds a generic list of Behaviours.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out. Basically even though the list of Behaviour is a property on Field, you still have to add that to the list of types that use the custom model binder in the Global.asax file

```
System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Types.Behaviour), new ConcreteTypeModelBinder());
```

With this line in place the type changing code I had worked a treat.